# jsplumb connector path for IE9

Tags: jsplumb

I'm having problem with JsPlumb connector paths. THe connector paths are coming straight for Firefox, Chrome, IE 10, IE 11. But they are taking 'S' type shape in IE 9. Please suggest

Comment: can you create a fiddle to demostrate the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response. I solved the issue. Actually I was working on someone else code. 
I fixed it by specifying the connnector parameters - stub, midpoint values. By this the connection is taking same values for all browsers